# Problems with starting an activity in onStart

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to start a floating activity from onStart to retrieve some info from the user right when the initial activity begins. I have the following:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
 super.onStart();
 callProfileDialog();
}
```

And `callProfileDialog()` is just:

```
private void callProfileDialog(){
 Intent i = new Intent(this, com.utility.ProfileDialog.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, PROFDIALOG);
}
```

`ProfileDialog.class` returns a String from an input box. If the result returned is `RESULT_CANCELED` then I restart the activity.

The problem I'm having is that when the program starts, the screen is just black. If I hit the Back button a `RESULT_CANCELED` is returned then the initial activity shows as well as the floating activity (since it recalled itself when it got a `RESULT_CANCELED`). Why can't I get the activities show by calling `ProfileDialog.class` from onStart()? I got the same result when I called it at the end of onCreate() which is way I switch over to use onStart(). Thanks for the help.

Edit: I have also tried the following:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    if(hasFocus)
    callProfileDialog();
}
```

But this doesn't work either. It all works fine once I hit the back button but without doing that, it's all black.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and got the behavior I wanted by overriding onAttachedToWindow() instead.

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    callProfileDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you don't have a valid context yet.  Try one of these:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    callProfileDialog();
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    callProfileDialog();
}
```

Comment: The first suggestion has the same problem as I currently do. The second suggestion though not only goes black but once I hit the back button it also keeps launching the floating activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `Activity.onActivityResult()` and set a flag that you are returning from a child, and only launch your new activity if that flag is not true:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  boolean returningFromChild = false;
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    returningFromChild = true;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    // Use your main layout here
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!returningFromChild) {
      callProfileDialog();
    }
    returningFromChild = false;
  }
}

// ProfileDialog.java
public class ProfileDialog extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle); 
    // Use your dialog layout here
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_dialog);

    // Use the id of your "OK" button here:
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveInput);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // XXX: Get / validate the user's input. Can add it to a new Intent object as an Extra, 
        // and use the setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); version:
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the same issue. It hangs on a black screen when I start the app. I still need to hit the back button for it to return a RESULT_CANCELED to get anything to show.

Comment: Are both activities (MainActivity, and ProfileDialog) calling `setContentView(R.layout.layout_resource_file);` ?  I must have read your initial question wrong; I thought the only problem was that it was continuously re-launching the dialog activity.

If you're just getting a black screen, that generally means you don't have any content in that activity (and the default theme is .Dark).

As for RESULT_CANCELED, are you calling `setResult(RESULT_OK, data);` in ProfileDialog after you've retrieved the input you want from the user?  And is there a button in ProfileDialog that will call `finish()`?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a more explicit flow of both the main activity, and your ProfileDialog activity, to show what is required to get back a RESULT_OK.